# Karate API Testing - How to use a variable (output from response) from API 1 to another API in same feature

Tags: karate

I have a scenario : 
Call API - Capture Response - Get ID from response and call another API which takes input ID from response 1.

Ex :

```
Feature: test graphql end point 

Background: 
    * url baseUrl + '/graphql'

Scenario: Create Org Call
    Given text query = 
        """
   mutation {
  test: createOrganization(
    name: "Org Name"
  )
  {
    Id
    name
  }
}
    """

And request { query: '#(query)' } 
When method post 
Then status 200 
* def res = response
* def id = res.data.test.Id
* print 'response:', response
* print 'Id:', id

Given text query = 
"""
mutation {
  createBackendHistory(orgId:  '#(id)') {
    orgId
  }
}
    """
And request { query: '#(query)' } 
When method post 
Then status 200
```

How to pass value(Id from call 1) is createBackendHistory API

When i try orgId:  '#(id)' i am getting error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `query` is `text` you can't use the `#()` embedded expressions. Please refer to the docs: https://github.com/intuit/karate#replace

Try this:

```
Given text query = 
"""
mutation {
  createBackendHistory(orgId:  '<id>') {
    orgId
  }
}
"""
And replace query.id = id
And request { query: '#(query)' } 
When method post 
Then status 200
```